# Tensorflow Keras Conv2D error with 2D numpy array input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I would like to train a CNN using a 2D numpy array as input, but I am receiving this error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (21, 21)`.

My input is indeed a 21x21 numpy array of floats. The first layer of the network is defined as `Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(21, 21, 1))` to match the shape of the input array.

I have found some similar questions but none pertaining to a 2D input array, they mostly deal with images. According to the documentation, Conv2D is expecting an input of a 4D tensor containing `(samples, channels, rows, cols)`, but I cannot find any documentation explaining the meaning of these values. Similar questions pertaining to image inputs suggest reshaping the input array using `np.ndarray.reshape()`, but when trying to do that I receive an input error.

How can I train a CNN on such an input array? Should `input_shape` be a different size tuple?

Answer (score 4):

Your current numpy array has dimensions `(21, 21)`. However, TensorFlow expects input tensors to have dimensions in the format `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` or **BHWC** implying that you need to convert your numpy input array to **4** dimensions (from the current **2** dimensions). One way to do so is as follows:

```
input = np.expand_dims(input, axis=0)
input = np.expand_dims(input, axis=-1)
```

Now, the numpy `input` array has dimensions: `(1, 21, 21, 1)` which can be passed to a TF Conv2D operation.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes thanks! I take a look to so many threads but this one works fine for me. My special case is that I create a synthetical image with the values 0 or 255. This starts from the np.zeros(width, height).